# iPhone Config Utility - show all devices in a provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, xcode

In both XCode and the iPhone Configuration Utility, there is a Provisioning Profiles item that shows at most 2 devices in a provisioning profile.  It also says "8 other devices".

- What are those devices?

Is there any convenient way to find out what those other 8 are (without going back to the provisioning portal?)

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the provisioning portal?

Comment: Why have the Prov Prof list at all if you're only going to show 2 devices?  There's nothing inherently wrong with the portal, just that (in a paradigm that worships fewer keystrokes), I have to switch to another app, log in, navigate to it, compare the profile names to the ones in XCode.  Not slick.

Comment: XCode 4 seems to show all of the info about the profile - much more useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open the .mobileprovision file in a text editor. You will see all the UDIDs under ProvisionedDevices key.

Comment: This is now out-dated, if you open it you'll get lots of lovely hex values?

Comment: Opening the file in a text editor still works - just search for "ProvisionedDevices". However, the file is encoded as a CMS message. You can view the actual contents of a .mobileprofile file using the `security` program on the command line, for example: `security cms -Di [file location]`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small program that shows all installed provision profiles and its devices. Application and source code are available from here

https://github.com/pigmasha/MAProvisions

Application features

- view all provision profiles installed on your computer
- select any profile and see its information and its devices list
- you can add names for your devices UDIDs
- objective-c note: all controls created programmatically (no .nib, .xib or .storyboard files)

Suggestions will be well received